# PHP Code Not Working in PHTML File

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, php

I am trying to integrate a Wordpress menu into a Boxbillng theme, but the problem is the PHP code I am using isn't being parsed at all.

Here is the code that gets the Wordpress menu:

```
<?php 
    include( '../wp-load.php' );
    wp_nav_menu( array ( 'menu' => 'Main Menu' ) );
?>
```

Then here is the code for the BoxBilling Theme:

```
<div class="main-navigation">
    <?php
        echo file_get_contents("http://www.glowstonehosting.net/nav.php");
    ?>
</div>
```

But then in Google Chrome Inspect Element it shows this:

```
 <!--?php
        echo file_get_contents("http://www.glowstonehosting.net/nav.php");
 ?-->
```

So they've all been commented out, I also tried one of the answers from another question simlilar to this: [php in .phtml file not parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598904/php-in-phtml-file-not-parsing)

The only answer suggested adding this to the Wordpress .htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
```

Which still didn't work so does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your link above, generated `Warning: include(../wp-load.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory...` so this tells me it's a path issue. Hence and in turn, the call to the function failed `Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_nav_menu()`.

Comment: .... Fred ummmm you dont have a local copy of the nav bar in that folder so how are you meant to be able to view it..............

Comment: By opening the URL in my browser. May or may not be relevant, but it did throw those errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: look i am not sure if this will break it or not, but rename file to .php and test to see if same issue persists.

Comment: You might try setting this in the main apache configuration instead of an .htaccess file. Find the existing `AddType` or `AddHandler` and insert it there.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The reason why you can't access it is because the site has a maintenance mode program installed over it.

Comment: Ok. Well, have you tried error reporting?

Comment: @Fred-ii- There are no errors, the issue is that the PHP in the PHTML file is being parsed as a comment and not PHP code.

Comment: Try adding this to your present `.htaccess` file `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .phtml`

Comment: Ok so I added that but nothing changed, it still thinks the PHP code are comments.

Comment: Someone posted an "answer" below with `AddHandler php-script .phtml` I myself, always post comments for questions like these. We can't assume success right off the bat; it's a presumption but could work. I never post "answers" till I know for sure something will indeed "work" and not "hope" it will work. ;-)

Comment: Another thing. If you're doing all this on your own server/PC and doing changes in Apache, make sure you've restarted Apache and all other related services, otherwise the changes won't take effect. @DanielAlexander

Comment: I'm with a host so htaccess is my only option. @Fred-ii-

Comment: Are you sure the host doesnt have something in place to prevent AddType/AddHandler or to impose an OuputFilter? Have you tested this outside of Wordpress and/or using a only `.php` extensions?

Comment: @prodigitalson Yes I have tested it with .php extensions but I have to use a .phtml file because that's the file my BoxBilling theme is using. It's just that the .phtml file won't read the PHP code as PHP but it reads it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the most simple approach is to create Twig extension and use it later in .phtml file.

Create a function:

```
public function get_contents($url)
{
    return file_get_contents($url);
}
```

Include it in twig filters list:

```
public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFilter('get_contents', array($this, 'get_contents')),
    );
}
```

and use it anywhere in Twig template:

```
{{ 'http://www.glowstonehosting.net/nav.php'|get_contents }}
```

[How to Write a custom Twig Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)

[Creating an extension for advanced users](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#creating-an-extension)

Answer (score -1):

`file_get_Contents` loads the file as a string, PHP is not interpreted. What you want is [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) which will interpret the php.

```
<div class="main-navigation">
    <?php
        include("some/filesystem/path/nav.php");
    ?>
</div>
```

Note the change in that you want to use the path to the file on the filesystem, presumably you are loading a file on the same server that is calling the include. If this is the case, you dont need to add the handlers unless you plan on hitting the php file directly via the webserver like `http://somedomain.com/somefile.phtml`

Comment: That has nothing to do with my problem, the problem is that the PHP is getting parsed as a comment and not a PHP script.

Comment: So you are actually trying to getcontents on a remote resource?

Comment: No, the nav.php file loads the Wordpress menu in HTML format and the boxbilling theme needs to load that file, that's all I need help with but the php is being parsed as a comment and not actual php code.

Comment: So `wp_nav_menu` gets includes or otherwise generates the block with the `div.main-navigation`?

Comment: It just gives you the HTML code for the menu which goes under the .main-navigation to use the CSS defined in .main-navigation